# Dynamics 365 Custom plugin not triggering

Tags: c#, plugins, microsoft-dynamics

I have a custom plugin that sets the default values for Account. Contact, and Opportunity to No when a Lead is Qualified:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PreOperationQualifyLead
{
    public class PreOperationQualifyLead : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            var orgFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            var orgService = (IOrganizationService)orgFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);
            //take the input parameters
            var isCreateAccount = (bool)context.InputParameters["CreateAccount"];
            var isCreateContact = (bool)context.InputParameters["CreateContact"];
            var isCreateOpportunity = (bool)context.InputParameters["CreateOpportunity"];
            var status = (Int32)context.InputParameters["Status"]; //3
            var leadEntRef = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            // add custom logic say and determine if you want to create a contact/ account or opportunity.
            // the below code will skip contact creation during Qualify process.
            context.InputParameters["CreateContact"] = false;
            context.InputParameters["CreateAccount"] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Plugin is registered to the SandBox instance for testing and Step is registered

[Plugin registration tool 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd3wL.png)

[Plugin registration tool 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUyI7.png)

In Plugin assemblies in Power Platform, I can see the plugin also there

[Power Platform plugins view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb0PU.png)

Also, the plugin step is there and it's On

[Power Platform plugin steps view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEjzb.png)

However, testing the plugin by Qualifying Lead is not doing anything, the values for Account and Contact are still by default Yes (instead of No as the plugin must do).

[CRM Qualify Lead Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udshK.png)

Note: Opportunity is No by default, so this values is not thanks to the plugin!

There are no System Jobs or Plugin-trace logs in CRM, so I'm guessing it is not running at all. Any Help what should I do from here to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'd recommend [Fake Xrm Easy](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy) for debugging and testing your plugin. It will let you mock a target entity record and step into your plugin code when debugging.

Comment: I think you are expecting the wrong thing here: The QualifyLead event isn't triggered until you confirm the dialog you interpret as the outcome. What you are trying to achieve should be baked into the Action Button that raises this dialog box.

Comment: You were right! I just teste it. So the question is how should I make this trigger when I press the QUalify button on the lead form, using the ribbon workbench?

Comment: Maybe it will be sufficient to just modify the parameters of the existing button action. Otherwise you will have to create your own client side script; publish as a web resource and modify the button action via Ribbon Workbench to use your script.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you mean by "Maybe it will be sufficient to just modify the parameters of the existing button action" Where is this have to happen or what should I use to do it, Is there any article example that you can provide me to guide me how to change an existing button parameters?

Comment: I'd recommend looking over [the Ribbon Workbench homepage](https://www.develop1.net/public/rwb/ribbonworkbench.aspx) - they over instructional videos. If you don't already use it, get [XrmToolbox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) but using Ribbon Workbench from the managed solution is also fine.

Comment: There are also [existing questions around Ribbon Command Parameters](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+ribbon+command+parameter) you might find helpful.